# Don't understand: "sort((a: Article, b: Article) => b.votes - a.votes);"

Tags: javascript, sorting, angular, typescript

I am not understanding the return statement in sortedArticles(). Can somone point me to a link, or explain how this sort function work?

```
sortedArticles(): Article[] {
    return this.articles.sort((a: Article, b: Article) => b.votes - a.votes);
}
```

---

```
<div class="ui grid posts">
  <app-article
    *ngFor="let article of sortedArticles()"
    [article]="article">
  </app-article>
</div>
```

May be a trivial question, but for some reason could not find the answer online. Appreciate the help.

Comment: it will return either a positive, zero or negative result, and that will be used for the sorting

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Have you read the docs on array sorting?

Comment: `this.something.sort(function (a,b) {return b.foo - a.foo;});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's break that down for you...

```
sortedArticles(): Article[] {
    return this.articles.sort((a: Article, b: Article) => b.votes - a.votes);
}
```

`(a: Article, b: Article) => b.votes - a.votes` - This is equivalent to
`function(a, b) { return b.votes - a.votes }`, and will return the proper values in order for `sort()` to be able to re-order the array elements. If the first article (`a`) has more votes, it'll return a negative value; if both articles have the same number of votes, it'll return `0`; if the second article (`b`) has more votes, it'll return a positive number.

`some_array.sort()` takes a function as its parameter. This can be a named function, or an anonymous function like is done here. It'll loop through the array and pass in two elements into the function to determine if they should be swapped or stay in that order. If the function returns a negative value, the first item should go before the second; if the function returns a positive value, the second item should go before the first; if the function returns `0`, then they're equally weighted, and their order doesn't matter -- the `sort()` usually puts them in their original order in this case.

So, calling `sortedArticles()` will return a list of articles, ordered by how many "votes" they each have.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb, did not realize this was the same as "function(a, b) { return b.votes - a.votes }" thank you!

Comment: For clarity, "calling `sortedArticles()` will return a list of articles in descending order of votes."